# MSMQ and ProtoBuf-Net serialization c#

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a class with many properties, one of them are byte[] property. I would like to send this class to another server using MSMQ. But before sending it I would like to serialize it using ProtoBuf-Net. Is it possible to attach ProtoBuf-Net serializer to MSMQ?

Frankly speaking I do not understand how to send class to queue. I have tried to use code below to put class to MSMQ queue but got exception "There was an error generating the XML document."

EntityBase is a class which I would like to send. Previously I have used my own File System based messaging system and ProtoBuf-Net to serialize class.

```
const string queueName = @".\private$\TestQueue";

private static void SendMessageToQueue(EntityBase entity)
{
    // check if queue exists, if not create it
    MessageQueue msMq = null;
    if (!MessageQueue.Exists(queueName))
    {
        msMq = MessageQueue.Create(queueName);
    }
    else
    {
        msMq = new MessageQueue(queueName);
    }
    try
    {

        msMq.Send(entity);
    }
    catch (MessageQueueException ee)
    {
        Console.Write(ee.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception eee)
    {
        Console.Write(eee.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        msMq.Close();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Message sent ......");
}
```

Comment: Protobug-Net? is that a quality judgement?

Comment: Sorry, Protobuf-NET, your product is excellent for serialization needs :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice would be: send either a `string` or a `byte[]` as the message; you can do this as:

```
byte[] body;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    Serializer.Serialize(ms, entity);
    body = ms.ToArray();
}
```

and then `Send(body)`, or if you want a `string`, then `Send(Convert.ToBase64String(body))`. And reverse this as the other end.

There looks to also be a mechanism for passing a `Message` along with an `IMessageFormatter`, but I'm not sure it is worth it. Example of reading:

```
Message msg = // receive
byte[] body = (byte[])msg.Body;
EntityBase entity;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream(body)) {
    entity = Serializer.Deserialize<EntityBase>(ms);
}
```

or (if choosing to pass a `string`):

```
string base64 = (string)msg.Body;
byte[] body = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
// as before
```