# Difference in Object deserialization with or without auto properties

Tags: c#

Can anyone explain to me why changing

from old style properties:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    private List<Bar> _BarList = new List<Bar>();

    public List<Bar> BarList
    {
        get
        {
            return _BarList;
        }
    }
}
```

to auto properties:

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> BarList { get; } = new List<Bar>();
}
```

would change the deserialization behavior?
After this change, the BarList property would always deserialize to NULL.

I always assumed this was just syntactic sugar, but I'm not brave enough to dive into the world of IL...

Comment: Can you show your deserialization code?

Comment: The behavior you talk about is the *deserializer's*.  Which one did you use? You shouldn't be able to set that property *at all* which means the deserializer tries to find and set the hidden field directly

Comment: It is a breaking change, be sure to bump up the [AssemblyVersion] so you get a good diagnostic for this instead of just null.

Comment: I've updated an old application which receives binary message form an MSQM queue, I used the standard System.Messaging.BinaryMessageFormatter which does the serialization for me.

Comment: @HansPassant I was under the impression that it wasn't, I've only updated the definition on the receiving end, thinking everything would still work...

Comment: @Kepar that standard way is generally frowned upon - the BinaryFormatter used has security issues because it can deserialize *anything* - any type, not just field contents. It's fragile too, as it serializes the fields themselves and the full type information, not the properties and thus can break if the types change, or even the *namespace* or *assembly version* changes. It's .NET *and* framework specific too, which means other applications, even written in .NET Core, won't be able to read those messages

Comment: @Kepar you should consider moving to a different serializer. If you check [BinaryMessageFormatter](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Messaging/System/Messaging/BinaryMessageFormatter.cs) you'll see that the code isn't complicated at all. You could write your own Json or Protobuf.net formatter. Check [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820913/msmq-and-protobuf-net-serialization-c-sharp) Protobuf.Net can handle read-only autoproperties too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're almost the same, but the compiler-generated backing field for the auto-prop is `readonly` (and has `[CompilerGenerated]` on it):

```
[CompilerGenerated]
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
private readonly List<Bar> <BarList>k__BackingField = new List<Bar>();

public List<Bar> BarList
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    get
    {
        return <BarList>k__BackingField;
    }
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAFgNwFgBQUDMCBMcAYgPYlYDeWcNCeAMgJYDOALgDwBCAhgE4B8cHryZs4FOAHMApq1RwAvnAC8cAHbSA7nFEdh/ABQBKDJgVZcBIX3GKgA=).

I suspect whatever serialization tool you're using is happy writing to private non-readonly fields, but refuses to write to private readonly fields.

In general though, it's a good idea to only serialize models which were written specifically to be serialized. These models can have properties with public setters.

Comment: It seems indeed that the readonly modifier is what got me. Thx!
also +1 for the link to SharpLab, didn't know this existed, gonna bookmark that one!

Answer (score 0):

The important information is in a comment - the serializer is BinaryMessageFormatter used to send/receive messages to MSMQ. This class uses the rather troublesome BinaryFormatter. That class isn't used a lot because it serializes entire types, including their metadata and *private fields*.

This means it's dangerous - it can deserialize anything. It's fragile - even an internal like a field rename will break deserialization. In fact, there are several SO questions where people have trouble deserializing from one assembly version number to the next. It'll definitely break with .NET Core for that reason.

This also means that even exchanging messages between different application versions can be troublesome.

A different serializer should be used, especially if the application is going to migrate to .NET Core. There's no need to explicitly use a message formatter, one can just serialize to `string` or `byte[]` and send that.

One option is to use eg Json.NET to generate JSON strings and send them as-is. The resulting string is far less verbose than XML and can be understood by any application. This can be as simple as :

```
var body=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someObject);
```

and

```
var message=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyMessage>(someObject);
```

Another option is to use [Protobuf.NET](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/wiki/Getting-Started) to serialize to protobuf, a compact serialization format created by Google that's also understood by all platforms. Protobuf.NET is maintained by StackOverflow programmers so we know it has great support.

The question [MSMQ and ProtoBuf-Net serialization c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820913/msmq-and-protobuf-net-serialization-c-sharp) asks just this. The necessary code is just as simple :

```
byte[] body;
using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
    Serializer.Serialize(ms, entity);
    body = ms.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I agree this seems like a better approach now, I will surely look into this for future projects!  although I must say this application has been running happily for over a decade with the BinaryMessageFormatter. I'm also not in a position where I can change all the different applications that put messages in this queue.
But my question was actually more regarding to the syntactic sugar of an auto property and why the serializer behaved differently for a class that (for me) looked identically, the answer from canton7 pointed me to the readonly modifier of the generated private field.